# apex:actionStatus: rendering stopText dynamically

Tags: visualforce, ajax

I have a button that updates some fields on a selected record. After update, I want to show the user the name of the updated record (the record was chosen by user via picklist)

Here's what I did:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Send" action="{!send}" status="status" />
<apex:actionStatus id="status"
    startText=" (sending...)" 
    stopText=" ( <Dynamic value> updated succesfully)" />
```

I would like to show the selected record name instead of `<Dynamic value>` inside `stopText` attribute. How to render the string of `stopText` dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use some variable in controller and use that to show the record name. Like, take a string variable "RecordName" and once you have updated the selected record, set "RecordName" to the name of that selected record. Once this will be set, you can use that on the vf Page.

Comment: Yes, that was a solution, thank you. In VF page, I access this variable like this: stopText="{!RecordName}"